# How to speed up calculation to find closest representation of the form N/2**M

Tags: python, performance, minimization

I want to find the closest representation of a floating point number in the form N/2**M in python, where N and M are integers. I attempted to use the minimisation function from scipy.optimise but it cannot be confined to the case where N and M are integers.

I ended up using a simple implementation that iterates through values of M and N and finds the minimum, but this is computationally expensive and time consuming for arrays of many numbers, what might be a better way of doing this?

My simple implementation is shown below:

```
import numpy as np

def ValueRepresentation(X):
    M, Dp = X
    return M/(2**Dp)

def Diff(X, value):
    return abs(ValueRepresentation(X) - value)

def BestApprox(value):
    mindiff = 1000000000
    for i in np.arange(0, 1000, 1):
        for j in np.arange(0, 60, 1):
            diff = Diff([i, j], value)            
            if diff < mindiff:
                mindiff = diff
                M = i
                Dp = j
    return M, Dp
```

Comment: Looping over both N and M is insanely inefficient.  Loop over M only (since that's the one with the smaller set of possible values), calculate the corresponding N, reject it if it's outside the allowed range for N.

Comment: also, you're using numpy but are still iterating with it on an individual basis, so you're not profiting at all from the possible array/matrix optimizations it might provide

Comment: Perhaps I'm overlooking something, but since you already have a specific floating point value, and since its binary representation already stores the exponent and mantissa in base 2, can't you just extract those values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the built-in functionality:

```
In [10]: 2.5.as_integer_ratio()  # get representation as fraction
Out[10]: (5, 2)

In [11]: (2).bit_length() - 1    # convert 2**M to M
Out[11]: 1
```

Note that all non-infinite, non-NaN floats are dyadic rationals, so we can rely on the denominator being an exact power of 2.

Comment: This is great if the values, N and M, can take any value but in my case abs(N) must be < 1000) and M cannot be greater than 32.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jasonharper I realised my implementation is ridiculously inefficient and could be much simpler.

The implementation of his method is shown below:

```
def BestApprox_fast(value):
    mindiff = 1000000000
    for Dp in np.arange(0, 32, 1):
        M = round(value*2**Dp)
        if abs(M) < 1000:
            diff = Diff([M, Dp], value)
            if diff < mindiff:
                mindiff = diff
                M_best = M
                Dp_best = Dp
    return M_best, Dp_best
```

It is approximately 200 times quicker.

Answer (score 0):

With the limits on M and N given, the range of N/2**M is a well defined discrete number scale:

[0-1000/2^26, 501-1000/2^25, 501-1000/2^24, ... 501-1000/2^1, 501-1000/2^0].

In this given discrete set, different subsets have different accuracy/resolution. The first subset [0-1000/2^26] has accuracy of 2^-26 or 26 binary bits resolution. So whenever the given number falls in the corresponding continuous domain [0,1000/2^26], the best accuracy achievable is 2^-26. Successively, the best accuracy is 2^25 when the given number is beyond the first domain but falls in domain [500/2^25,1000/2^25], which corresponds to the second subset [501-1000/2^25]. (Note the difference between discrete set and continuous domain.)

With the above logic, we know the best accuracy, defined by M, depends on where the given number falls on the scale. Thus we can implement it as following python code:

```
import numpy as np

limits = 1000.0/2**np.arange(0,61)

a = 103.23    # test value
for i in range(60,-1,-1):
    if a <= limits[i]:
        N = i
        M = round(a * 2**N)
        r = [M, N]
        break

if a > 1000:
    r = [round(a), 0]
```

This solution has O(c) execution time, so it is ideal for multiple invocations.